# I want to add " into a string that is surrounded by ""

Tags: ios

Current code is:

```
detailsLabel.text = " "Hi" "
```

This doesn't work though because it believes when I type the " into "" it thinks I am adding a new string... Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
detailsLabel.text = " \"Hi\" "
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great